Vertex Feynman rules for scalar QED
I am self-studying QFT using the Schwartz book "Quantum field theory and the standard model", and I am reading chapter 9 about  Scalar QED.
At page 143 he shows the fours possible vertex (at first order perturbation) for the following interaction terms in the Lagrangian:
$$
-ieA_\mu[\phi^*(\partial_\mu\phi)-(\partial_\mu\phi^*)\phi].\tag{9.16}
$$
Below an example of vertex:

He states that this vertex is equal to:
$$
ie(-p^1_\mu - p^2_\mu),\tag{9.17}
$$
and motivated it merely saying that the derivative $\partial_\mu$, acting on the exponential $e^{ipx}$ in the scalar fields $\phi$ and $\phi^*$, pull down the $p_\mu$ term.
Based on what I have studied so far, the Feynman rules in momentum space comes from the LSZ formula, the Wicks theorem and the Feynman propagator, and this calculation involves also integrals on $d^4p$
However, he calculated all that previous stuff on product of the scalar fields like $\phi(x)\phi(y)$, while now we have product like $\phi(x)\partial_\mu\phi(y)$, and as he also mention, the derivative $\partial_\mu$ acting on the exponential $e^{ipx}$ in the scalar fields $\phi$ and $\phi^*$, pull down the $p_\mu$ term.
So saying easily that it adds the factor $p_\mu$ in the vertex, seems to me like a guess, not a proof.
Am I missing some concept that makes that short "proof" more clear and rigorous.
I would appreciated also suggestions for books that have in deep proof of the Feynman rules for scalar QED.
EDIT: I have found the full calculation in Greiner-Reinhardt book "Field quantization" page 251-261, that seems to confirm the "proof" in Schwartz book is very naïve.
The part specific to this question is in the equations (25),(26),(27),(28) where it shows that the contraction of $\phi(x)$ with $\partial_\mu\phi^*(y)$ is equal to $i\partial_\mu\Delta_F(x-y)$,  where $\Delta_F(x-y)$ is the usual Feynman propagator for scalar field
This is not trivial, cause $\partial_\mu$ doesn't commute with the time-ordering operator $T$, due to the Heaviside's unit step function $\Theta(x_0-y_0)$ inside. The derivative of $\Theta$ is the Dirac Delta

Vertices can be also derived from functional differentiation of the interaction term in Fourier. Hence the change $\partial_\mu \leadsto p_\mu$.
